# trying ffmpeg with intel quicksync, "Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)

Tags: ffmpeg, intel-graphics

Often I do ffmpeg without intel quicksync, e.g. having made a subdirectory called "a", `ffmpeg -i IMG_0001.MOV -c:a libmp3lame -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ffff.mp4`

(I know mp3 in mp4 container is a bit old fashioned, and aac is the current convention/standard, but my old video editor doesn't like aac in there. And I know libx264 is a bit low quality these days, but it has been ok for me and  I don't think it's the source of the problem here)

I want to try encoding with intel quicksync, as  I understand it's faster.

The processor on the laptop i am using is i5 3230m  which supports quicksync https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/72056/intel-core-i53230m-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz-bga.html

I do the command `ffmpeg -i IMG_0030.MOV -acodec copy -vcodec h264_qsv blah.mp4`

But I get the error

```
[h264_qsv @ 00000000004ddd40] Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width
or height
Conversion failed!
```

--

```
G:\vids\apple> ffmpeg -i IMG_0030.MOV -acodec copy -vcodec h264_qsv blah.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0030.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2022-06-01T13:55:35.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 4.782269
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +51.9016-000.2051+094.310/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 11 Pro
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 15.3.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2022-06-01T14:55:34+0100
  Duration: 00:00:11.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22869 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 22685 kb/s, 119.99 fps, 120 tbr, 2400 tbn, 2400 tbc (defa
ult)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2022-06-01T13:55:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-06-01T13:55:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
File 'blah.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_qsv @ 00000000004ddd40] Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width
or height
Conversion failed!
```

also

I notice that h264_qsv is listed by `ffmpeg -encoders` which I guess maybe means the ffmpeg build supports it

```
C:\Users\User>ffmpeg -encoders | grep 264
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
 V..... libx264              libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (codec h264)
 V..... libx264rgb           libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 RGB (codec h264)
 V..... h264_amf             AMD AMF H.264 Encoder (codec h264)
 V..... h264_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... h264_qsv             H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc                NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc_h264           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
```

**added**

Here is an attempt with this command So, specifying crf, as a comment suggested `ffmpeg -i IMG_0001.MOV -c:a copy -c:v h264_qsv -crf 23 aaa.mp4`

And it says "[h264_qsv @ 00000000003804c0]" in a cyan colour, followed by in red,  "[h264_qsv @ 00000000003804c0] Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

And then in grey,  "Conversion failed!"  as you see below

```
G:\vids\apple>ffmpeg -i IMG_0001.MOV -c:a copy -c:v h264_qsv -crf 23 aaa.mp4

ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0001.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 20.738540
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +51.6208-000.2740+066.132/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 11 Pro
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.8
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2022-02-26T21:21:16+0000
  Duration: 00:00:01.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12855 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 12623 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (defau
lt)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-26T21:21:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
File 'aaa.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_qsv @ 00000000001504c0] Error initializing the encoder: invalid video parameters (-15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width
or height
Conversion failed!

G:\vids\apple>
```

If I change -c:a copy  to -c:a libmp3lame then I also get this message though in yelloe "Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (aaa.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most li
kely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually use d for any stream.".  When I don't specify the -crf, then I don't get that message.

Comment: You do not specify _any_ codec parameters. Try again with at least quality (CRF or otherwise) specified.

Comment: @DanielB  doesn't crf have a default value of 23 anyway  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 " 23 is the default"  So i figured not specifying it shouldn't relate to that error.  But now i've added some examples with crf specified

Comment: @barlop Try updating Intel HD Graphics driver and update FFmpeg. There is a tool from Intel named "`msdk_sys_analyzer_64.exe`", that gives a list of supported QuickSync capabilities (part of Intel Media SDK). I found a workaround for sharing this tool (in case you don't want to download and install Intel Media SDK): **1.** Download [t2XKa.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2XKa.png). **2.** Execute: `ffmpeg -y -i t2XKa.png -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray msdk_sys_analyzer_64.exe`. **3.** Make sure it's not a virus...